# How to dynamically set public key pinning in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, ssl

i want to implement dynamically set public key / certificate pinning which i can get it from API, and then set it into react native application. It can prevent deploy app to play store / apple store every certificate expired and every we add new certificate / public key for new trusted domain.

Any one can help , which library can be used or what kind of approach ? many thanks

Comment: Don't think that's possible since the pinned key or cert is configured in XCode and built with the native bundle. You can pin a long-lived CA key or cert instead of a short-lived leaf one.

Comment: I think this can be done by just getting public key or cert file from one of the api just like we have api to get json data or a file download. But this has a security issue can intruders can use save api end to get same credentials and bypass ssl pinning you have implemented. 

There is no sense in implementing dynamic key or cert.

Comment: Have you find a way to solve it?